# How to get tAda?

Tags: cardano-faucet

Currently tAda faucet is down ("We are curently experiencing techincal issues with the faucet"). Please bear with us while we get this sorted"). Is there any alternative to get tAda?
If anybody can help by sending me tAda, below is my address :
addr_test1qzea2taqlalpquy8mysrzu399lrqwyn3rh0j6uxlhrlrm8kdvc7hex6r9hyqh0pfwa4creandeuv0cv8slyj5qrwzurqk3a0gn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The faucet worked for me just now, even though it shows the message: "We are curently experiencing techincal issues with the faucet. Please bear with us while we get this sorted".

It only took about 1 minute to complete.

I've sent you 750 tADA anyway, just in case.

Comment: Thank you so much, received tAda you sent.

Comment: Also I've just tried the faucet, it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine. Just the API on the wallet is responding really slowly because the tx history has ballooned recently. We'll fix this when we get a chance but ignore the server error for now. I've tested it a couple times and eventually received the funds about 10 minutes after I requested.

Comment: Here the screenshot of the faucet experiencing [server error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L6xHMoTGyF16CTx1BB7zM11iMPfdTQN_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: great reaction Samuel,
thanks for the update and verification.

Answer (score 0):

please find here all info,
and you can request them

To request tokens using the faucet:

https://testnets.cardano.org/en/testnets/cardano/tools/faucet/

Comment: The problem is currently the faucet in that link is down. Is there any alternative?

Comment: another try i would do by join the groups below, - either telegram, https://t.me/CardanoStakePoolWorkgroup - or cardano forum forum.cardano.org/ - and ask people if they have to share them with you.